# Getting data from NSDictinionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, foursquare

I'm trying to get the "firstName" , "lastName" , "gender", "homeCity" and "email" from a NSDictionary

but It doesn't work...I have tried the following code:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo  = [fsUser getUserInfo:@"self"];

NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"firstName"]);
NSLog(@"lastName: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"lastName"]);
NSLog(@"gender: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"gender"]);
NSLog(@"homeCity: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"homeCity"]);
NSLog(@"email: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"email"]);
```

here is my dictionary value...

```
  userInfo: {

userDictionary =     {
    meta =         {
        code = 200;
        errorDetail = "Please provide an API version to avoid future errors.See http://bit.ly/vywCav";
        errorType = deprecated;
    };
    notifications =         (
                    {
            item =                 {
                unreadCount = 0;
            };
            type = notificationTray;
        }
    );
    response =         {
        user =             {
            badges =                 {
                count = 0;
                items =                     (
                );
            };
            bio = "";
            checkinPings = off;
            checkins =                 {
                count = 0;
            };
            contact =                 {
                email = "email@email.com";
            };
            firstName = Name;
            following =                 {
                count = 0;
            };
            friends =                 {
                count = 0;
                groups =                     (
                                            {
                        count = 0;
                        items =                             (
                        );
                        name = "Amigos em comum";
                        type = friends;
                    },
                                            {
                        count = 0;
                        items =                             (
                        );
                        name = "Outros amigos";
                        type = others;
                    }
                );
            };
            gender = male;
            homeCity = "";
            id = 3233312;
            lastName = lastName;
            lists =                 {
                groups =                     (
                                            {
                        count = 1;
                        items =                             (
                        );
                        type = created;
                    }
                );
            };
            mayorships =                 {
                count = 0;
                items =                     (
                );
            };
            photo = "https://foursquare.com/img/blank_boy.png";
            photos =                 {
                count = 0;
                items =                     (
                );
            };
            pings = 0;
            referralId = "u-sdsad";
            relationship = self;
            requests =                 {
                count = 0;
            };
            scores =                 {
                checkinsCount = 0;
                goal = 50;
                max = 0;
                recent = 0;
            };
            tips =                 {
                count = 0;
            };
            todos =                 {
                count = 0;
            };
            type = user;
        };
    };
};
   }
```

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'. Compiler error? No logs? House burns down?

Comment: Why do you assume that all the nested objects will just be automatically found?  You need to go down each level of the dictionary one by one.  First get "userDictionary" then get "response" then get "user" etc, etc.  Learn about data structures man, this stuff isn't that complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[userInfo objectForKey:@"userDictionary"] objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"homeCity"]`.

Comment: @AranhaSilva If my answer is correct, can you mark as accepted?

Comment: thx, it works. And I did mark as accepted because was the first full answer

Answer (score 2):

This is where key-value coding (KVC) comes in handy. You can do (note use of `valueForKey:`:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [fsUser getUserInfo:@"self"];
NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user.firstName"]);
NSLog(@"lastName: %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user.lastName"]);
NSLog(@"gender: %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user.gender"]);
NSLog(@"homeCity: %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user.homeCity"]);
NSLog(@"email: %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user.email"]);
```

But this isn't very efficient since you keep digging deep into the same dictionary. It would be better to do this:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [fsUser getUserInfo:@"self"];
NSDictionary *user = [userInfo valueForKey:@"response.user"];
NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [user objectForKey:@"firstName"]);
NSLog(@"lastName: %@", [user objectForKey:@"lastName"]);
NSLog(@"gender: %@", [user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
NSLog(@"homeCity: %@", [user objectForKey:@"homeCity"]);
NSLog(@"email: %@", [user objectForKey:@"email"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your `userInfo` doesn't have such keys.

`userInfo` has `userDictionary`, which has `meta`, `notifications` and `response`.

`response` has `user`, and `user` has `firstName`, `lastName` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your top leve is userInfo, but there are "objects" within that as well. You will have to traverse those to get to first name. Something like this will work:

```
NSLog(@"first name = %@", userInfo[@"userInfo"][@"userDictionary"][@"response"][@"user"][@"firstName"]);
```